# Count specific numbers if first column match

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I have a table with the following entries:

[image: Excel list with entries]

When I want to count the "1" on every line which starts with J I can use the following Formula

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5;"J";B1:B5;"1")
```

The result is shown here:

[image: Result of COUNTIF]

When I now add some collums more and expand the COUNTIF Excel only shows "**#VALUE!**"

Printscreen:

[image]

How can I count all "1" when the first cell in the line starts with "J"?

Comment: so each `1` or each row that has at least one `1` in it?  and what version do you have?

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner I want to count all `1` that are on a line which has a `J` in the "Colum A"
So based on my last printscreen it would be `4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and two Boolean statements.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="J")*(B1:D5=1))
```

[image]